# SAPUI5 Planning Calendar - cannot bind appointments in xml view to appointments in model

Tags: javascript, json, xml, sapui5

I wrote an application which includes Planning Calendar SAPUI5 control. I was inspired by this demo:
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendarSingle/preview

I have a problem with binding model to Calendar control in xml view.

In above demo, model is hardcoded inside a controller and looks like this:

```
var oModel = new JSONModel();
            oModel.setData({
                startDate: new Date("2017", "0", "08", "8", "0"),
                people: [{
                    name: "John Miller",
                    appointments: [{
                        start: new Date("2016", "10", "15", "10", "0"),
                        end: new Date("2016", "11", "25", "12", "0"),
                        title: "Team collaboration",
                        info: "room 1",
                        type: "Type01",
                        pic: "sap-icon://sap-ui5",
                        tentative: false
                    },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2016", "09", "13", "9", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2016", "01", "09", "10", "0"),
                            title: "Reminder",
                            type: "Type06"
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2016", "07", "10", "0", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2016", "09", "16", "23", "59"),
                            title: "Vacation",
                            info: "out of office",
                            type: "Type04",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2016", "07", "1", "0", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2016", "09", "31", "23", "59"),
                            title: "New quarter",
                            type: "Type10",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "03", "0", "01"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "04", "23", "59"),
                            title: "Workshop",
                            info: "regular",
                            type: "Type07",
                            pic: "sap-icon://sap-ui5",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "05", "08", "30"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "05", "09", "30"),
                            title: "Meet Donna Moore",
                            type: "Type02",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "08", "10", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "08", "12", "0"),
                            title: "Team meeting",
                            info: "room 1",
                            type: "Type01",
                            pic: "sap-icon://sap-ui5",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "09", "0", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "09", "23", "59"),
                            title: "Vacation",
                            info: "out of office",
                            type: "Type02",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "11", "0", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "12", "23", "59"),
                            title: "Education",
                            info: "",
                            type: "Type03",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "16", "00", "30"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "16", "23", "30"),
                            title: "New Product",
                            info: "room 105",
                            type: "Type04",
                            tentative: true
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "18", "11", "30"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "18", "13", "30"),
                            title: "Lunch",
                            info: "canteen",
                            type: "Type03",
                            tentative: true
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "20", "11", "30"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "20", "13", "30"),
                            title: "Lunch",
                            info: "canteen",
                            type: "Type03",
                            tentative: true
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "18", "0", "01"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "19", "23", "59"),
                            title: "Working out of the building",
                            type: "Type07",
                            pic: "sap-icon://sap-ui5",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "23", "08", "00"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "24", "18", "30"),
                            title: "Discussion of the plan",
                            info: "Online meeting",
                            type: "Type04",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "25", "0", "01"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "26", "23", "59"),
                            title: "Workshop",
                            info: "regular",
                            type: "Type07",
                            pic: "sap-icon://sap-ui5",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "2", "30", "10", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "4", "33", "12", "0"),
                            title: "Working out of the building",
                            type: "Type07",
                            pic: "sap-icon://sap-ui5",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "8", "1", "00", "30"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "10", "15", "23", "30"),
                            title: "Development of a new Product",
                            info: "room 207",
                            type: "Type03",
                            tentative: true
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "1", "15", "10", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "2", "25", "12", "0"),
                            title: "Team collaboration",
                            info: "room 1",
                            type: "Type01",
                            pic: "sap-icon://sap-ui5",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "2", "13", "9", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "3", "09", "10", "0"),
                            title: "Reminder",
                            type: "Type06"
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "03", "10", "0", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "05", "16", "23", "59"),
                            title: "Vacation",
                            info: "out of office",
                            type: "Type04",
                            tentative: false
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "07", "1", "0", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "09", "31", "23", "59"),
                            title: "New quarter",
                            type: "Type10",
                            tentative: false
                        }
                    ],
                    headers: [
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "08", "0", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "08", "23", "59"),
                            title: "National holiday",
                            type: "Type04"
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "10", "0", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "10", "23", "59"),
                            title: "Birthday",
                            type: "Type06"
                        },
                        {
                            start: new Date("2017", "0", "17", "0", "0"),
                            end: new Date("2017", "0", "17", "23", "59"),
                            title: "Reminder",
                            type: "Type06"
                        }
                    ]
                }
                ]
            });
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
```

XML view on the other hand, looks like this:

```
<PlanningCalendar
        id="PC1"
        showRowHeaders="false"
        startDate="{path: '/startDate'}"
        viewKey="Day"
        rows="{path: '/people'}"
        appointmentsVisualization="Filled"
        appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect"
        intervalSelect="handleIntervalSelect"
        showEmptyIntervalHeaders="false">
        <toolbarContent>
            <Title text="Title" titleStyle="H4"/>
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <ToggleButton icon="sap-icon://decrease-line-height"
                          tooltip="Toggle Day Names Line"
                          press="toggleDayNamesLine"/>
        </toolbarContent>
        <rows>
            <PlanningCalendarRow
                appointments="{path : 'appointments', templateShareable: 'true'}"
                intervalHeaders="{path: 'headers', templateShareable: 'true'}">
                <appointments>
                    <unified:CalendarAppointment
                        startDate="{start}"
                        endDate="{end}"
                        icon="{pic}"
                        title="{title}"
                        text="{info}"
                        type="{type}"
                        tentative="{tentative}">
                    </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                </appointments>
                <intervalHeaders>
                    <unified:CalendarAppointment
                        startDate="{start}"
                        endDate="{end}"
                        icon="{pic}"
                        title="{title}"
                        type="{type}">
                    </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                </intervalHeaders>
            </PlanningCalendarRow>
        </rows>
    </PlanningCalendar>
```

I copied exact same code with one difference. My model is not a default view model, but it has an ID:

```
this.getView().setModel(oModel, "calendarModel");
```

Of course, because of that change I cannot write in my xml view:

```
rows="{path: '/people'}"
```

Instead, I wrote something like this:

```
<PlanningCalendar id="PC1" showRowHeaders="false" startDate="{path: '/startDate'}" viewKey="Day" rows="{path: 'calendarModel>/people'}"
                                    appointmentsVisualization="Filled" appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect" intervalSelect="handleIntervalSelect"
                                    showEmptyIntervalHeaders="false">
                                    <toolbarContent>
                                        <Title text="Title" titleStyle="H4"/>
                                        <ToolbarSpacer/>
                                        <ToggleButton icon="sap-icon://decrease-line-height" tooltip="Toggle Day Names Line" press="toggleDayNamesLine"/>
                                    </toolbarContent>
                                    <rows>
                                        <PlanningCalendarRow appointments="{path : 'appointments', templateShareable: 'true'}" intervalHeaders="{path: 'headers', templateShareable: 'true'}">
                                            <appointments>
                                                <unified:CalendarAppointment startDate="{start}" endDate="{end}" icon="{pic}" title="{title}" text="{info}" type="{type}"
                                                    tentative="{tentative}"></unified:CalendarAppointment>
                                            </appointments>
                                            <intervalHeaders>
                                                <unified:CalendarAppointment startDate="{start}" endDate="{end}" icon="{pic}" title="{title}" type="{type}"></unified:CalendarAppointment>
                                            </intervalHeaders>
                                        </PlanningCalendarRow>
                                    </rows>
                                </PlanningCalendar>
```

The problem is, I can't see any appointments. Planning calendar control still shows one row (because there is only one person in that model), but it's totally empty.

I suspect, there is something wrong with my path:

```
<PlanningCalendarRow appointments="{path : 'appointments', templateShareable: 'true'}" intervalHeaders="{path: 'headers', templateShareable: 'true'}">
```

But I have no idea how to write it correctly.

Important note: If I change my "calendarModel" model to default view model (without ID), everything works perfectly fine. I can see all appointments from my model.

Comment: add the model name to everything, not just the first entry: `path: 'calendarModel>appointments'`, `{calendarModel>tentative}` etc etc

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help :/ Still, I can't see any appointments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you gave your model a name you need to specify it on your bindings. This should work:

```
<mvc:View
    controllerName="sap.m.sample.PlanningCalendar.Page"
    xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns:unified="sap.ui.unified"
    xmlns="sap.m">
    <VBox class="sapUiSmallMargin">
        <PlanningCalendar
            id="PC1"
            startDate="{model: 'calendarModel', path: '/startDate'}"
            rows="{model: 'calendarModel', path: '/people'}"
            appointmentsVisualization="Filled"
            appointmentSelect="handleAppointmentSelect"
            showEmptyIntervalHeaders="false"
            showWeekNumbers="true">
            <toolbarContent>
                <Title text="Title" titleStyle="H4"/>
            </toolbarContent>
            <rows>
                <PlanningCalendarRow
                    icon="{pic}"
                    title="{name}"
                    text="{role}"
                    appointments="{model: 'calendarModel', path : 'appointments', templateShareable: 'true'}"
                    intervalHeaders="{model: 'calendarModel', path: 'headers', templateShareable: 'true'}">
                    <customData>
                        <core:CustomData key="emp-name" value="{calendarModel>name}" writeToDom="true"/>
                    </customData>
                    <appointments>
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment
                            startDate="{calendarModel>start}"
                            endDate="{calendarModel>end}"
                            icon="{calendarModel>pic}"
                            title="{calendarModel>title}"
                            text="{calendarModel>info}"
                            type="{calendarModel>type}"
                            tentative="{calendarModel>tentative}">
                        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                    </appointments>
                    <intervalHeaders>
                        <unified:CalendarAppointment
                            startDate="{calendarModel>start}"
                            endDate="{calendarModel>end}"
                            icon="{calendarModel>pic}"
                            title="{calendarModel>title}"
                            type="{calendarModel>type}">
                        </unified:CalendarAppointment>
                    </intervalHeaders>
                </PlanningCalendarRow>
            </rows>
        </PlanningCalendar>
        <Label text="Add available built-in views to the example:"/>
        <MultiComboBox
                selectionFinish="handleSelectionFinish"
                width="230px"
                placeholder="Choose built-in views">
            <items>
                <core:Item key="Hour" text="Hour" />
                <core:Item key="Day" text="Day" />
                <core:Item key="Month" text="Month" />
                <core:Item key="Week" text="1 week" />
                <core:Item key="One Month" text="1 month" />
            </items>
        </MultiComboBox>
    </VBox>
</mvc:View>
```